# Pluck with condtions in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to compare a param extracted from a link to the list of data present in column...
I am using pluck to generate a array of list(in controller) but not getting any success in comparing it

any  method that I can fetch records in model and compare with param in controller or model
as passing controller instances in model seems inappropriate to me
Initially i am trying fetching and comparing in controller..

```
  @abc=Group.pluck(:group_token)
```

what I tried to do before is defined group_fetch method in model and used it in controller to check condition but I was not able to compare param which comes frome url dynamically

```
  def self.group_fetch
    Group.find_by group_token: 'UuzsG7NMvYFzxwPDdYgLxJbF'
  end
```

what will be the best way to fetch db column and compare it with the link param

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`exists?`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-exists-3F) method which pretty much does what it says.

```rb
Group.exists?(group_token: params[:token])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `include?` to check if the param is in the list. For example:

```rb
def your_method
  list = Model.pluck(:attribute)
  list.include?(params[:your_param])
end
```